# Small blobs of tar on a (5 year old) flat tar and gravel roof

Tags: repair, roof, gravel

I have noticed several cluster of small blobs of tar on my flat tar and gravel roof which was renovated 5 years ago.

I tried to remove one blob ([here is a video](https://photos.app.goo.gl/8AochpCD9yw8rbLt7)) and it seemed to be full with no cavities inside it.

Are these something of concern? Should I put extra gravel on top of these?

I appreciate opinions! Thanks!

### Close up view

[image: tar blobs on roof, close view]

### Further view

[image: tar blobs on roof, far view]

Comment: I would be much more concerned about the source of the disembodied hand on your roof. Oh, wait, that's just a glove...

Comment: I thought it was Thing from the Addams family!  Gotta have some fun here once in a while.

Comment: I laughed so hard @FreeMan! It put it there to give a sense of dimension!

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a pocket or thick point there I probably would not mess with them as some may be connected. I probably would get some white paint and paint that area white, the tar is getting hot and bubbling up. White will help it to reflect the heat and not bubble up making a low point.

Answer (score 0):

I asked a roof repair company (over the phone) about this and they said that this is normal and no action is required.

They said that this has probably happened right after renovation; tar has bubbled up after applying the gravel while it was hot.

Note that this is in Quebec, Canada for reference.